# AHK to group files by Type

Tags: autohotkey

How can I script a AHK to group files in **Windows 10** explorer by Type and Sort by Date

This is the script I have now for Details layout and sort by name.

```
#o:: ; Win+O
PostMessage, 0x111, 28747,, SHELLDLL_DefView1, A ;View, Details
;PostMessage, 0x111, 28753,, SHELLDLL_DefView1, A ;View, List
PostMessage, 0x111, 31492,, SHELLDLL_DefView1, A ;View, Sort by, Name ;toggle ascending/descendingreturn
```

I would lile to expand this to **Group** by **Type** and **Sort** by **DATE**